# Twilio API and Vue.JS

Tags: vue.js, twilio-api

I'm trying to send a message using Twilio API  my code is

```
  const accountSid = "";
  const authToken = "";
  const client = require("twilio")(accountSid, authToken);

  client.messages
    .create({
      body: "Hello from Test",
      to: "+1843", // Text this number
      from: "+1843" // From a valid Twilio number
    })
    .then(message =>
      console
        .log(message.sid)

        .catch(e => {
          console.error("Got an error:", e.code, e.message);
        })
    );
```

I added twilio to my vue project using npm.  I see it referenced in my package.json.  When I try to create the client I get an error saying Webpack does not support require.  I know that I am not using Import correctly but it does not seem that I can get much help from Twilio with any type of sample code. 
I know there are a couple of experts with Twilio and Vue and I was hoping that they can send me in the right direction.  All I want to do is send a message.  I don't need to receive or log anything, just send.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api

Comment: "Important Note - Server Side only, not Front End"

You should create on node express server and call it as an api.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node

Comment: That's part of my confusion.  I totally agree that their SMS programmable code is server based but their newer API's imply that they are not.  An email I got back from Twilio stated "In relation to your query, you can indeed send a request to Twilio to send your message. You can do so in node like so:"

Answer (score 0):

You need a proper backend what handles the request, or you can use curl to make the request.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      authToken: '[AuthToken]',
      accountSid: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      to: 'whatsapp:+xxxxxxxx',
      from: 'whatsapp:+xxxxxxx',
      messageBody: 'Nieuwe vraag',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    sendMessage() {
      const url = `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/${this.accountSid}/Messages.json`;
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append('To', this.to);
      data.append('From', this.from);
      data.append('Body', this.messageBody);

      const headers = {
        Authorization: `Basic ${btoa(`${this.accountSid}:${this.authToken}`)}`,
      };

      fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers,
        body: data,
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log('Message sent', data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error sending message', error);
        });
    },
  },
};
```